# Luhn's Algorithm not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

For those who are familiar with Luhn's Algorithm, I am compiling a program that verify credit card numbers using this Algorithm. Here's what I have already:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String ccNum = "";
int product = 0;
int sum = 0;

System.out.print("Please enter a credit card #: ");
ccNum = input.next();

for(int i = 0 + 1; i < ccNum.length(); i--){
    int number = Integer.parseInt(ccNum.substring(i, i + 1));

    if(i % 2 != 0){
        product = number * 1;
    }
    else{
        product = number * 2;
    }
    if(product > 9){
        product -= 9;
        sum += product;
    }
}
boolean valid = (sum % 10 == 0);
if(valid){
    System.out.println("Valid!");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Invalid!");
}
}

}
```

I am confused about this program. When I run it, I got the "StringIndexOutOfBoundsExpection" error. What should I change up? We cannot use arrays with this program, however. Instead of the full 16-digit number, we are only using 8 digits.

Comment: `i--` are you sure about that?

Comment: You know there are plenty of implementation for Luhn out there I think there is one in the Apaches commons codec library

Comment: I'm going to check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    boolean alt = false;
    for(int i = ccNum.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--, alt = !alt){
        int number = ccNum.charAt(i) - '0';
        if(alt)
            number *= 2;
        if(number > 9)
            number -= 9;
        sum += number;
    }
    boolean valid = (sum % 10 == 0);
```

Comment: It's still giving me "Invalid" for all of my inputs.